# Why is there "==> append : to filename to view the PDF source" at the beginning of the output of `less` on pdf files

Tags: pdf, less

When I use `less` to view the text part of a pdf file, I get

> ==> append : to filename to view the PDF source

appended to the beginning of the output.

Why does that happen? How can I suppress it?

```
$ less --version:

less 600 (POSIX regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2022  Mark Nudelman

less comes with NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
For information about the terms of redistribution,
see the file named README in the less distribution.
Home page: https://greenwoodsoftware.com/less
```

and

```
$ env | grep LESS
LESSOPEN=|/nix/store/vikaff8688ghqpxa69ir9n3szbyphqy5-lesspipe-1.85/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
LESSKEYIN_SYSTEM=/nix/store/9xijfbnbfvz9287s459n1p2qi0l3gpdv-lessconfig
```

and

```
$ less /nix/store/vikaff8688ghqpxa69ir9n3szbyphqy5-lesspipe-1.85/bin/lesspipe.sh

#!/nix/store/iffl6dlplhv22i2xy7n1w51a5r631kmi-bash-5.1-p16/bin/bash
# lesspipe.sh, a preprocessor for less (version 1.83)
#===============================================================================
### THIS FILE IS GENERATED FROM lesspipe.sh.in, PLEASE GET THE ZIP FILE
### from https://github.com/wofr06/lesspipe.sh/archive/lesspipe.zip
### AND RUN configure TO GENERATE A lesspipe.sh THAT WORKS IN YOUR ENVIRONMENT
#===============================================================================
#
# Usage:   lesspipe.sh is called when the environment variable LESSOPEN is set:
#      LESSOPEN="|lesspipe.sh %s"; export LESSOPEN  (sh like shells)
#      setenv LESSOPEN "|lesspipe.sh %s"        (csh, tcsh)
#      Use the fully qualified path if lesspipe.sh is not in the search path
#      View files in multifile archives:
#           less archive_file:contained_file
#      This can be used to extract ASCII files from a multifile archive:
#           less archive_file:contained_file>extracted_file
#      As less is not good for extracting raw data use instead:
#           lesspipe.sh archive_file:contained_file>extracted_file
#          Even a file in a multifile archive that itself is contained in yet
#          another archive can be viewed this way:
#           less super_archive:archive_file:contained_file
#      Display the last file in the file1:..:fileN chain in raw format:
#      Suppress input filtering:    less file1:..:fileN:   (append a colon)
#      Suppress decompression:  less file1:..:fileN::  (append 2 colons)
#
# Required programs and supported formats: see the separate file README
# License: GPL (see file LICENSE)
# History: see the separate file ChangeLog
# Author:  Wolfgang Friebel, DESY (Wolfgang.Friebel AT desy.de)
#
#===============================================================================
( [[ -n 1 && -n 2 ]] ) > /dev/null 2>&1 || exec zsh -y --ksh-arrays -- "$0" ${1+"$@"}
#setopt KSH_ARRAYS SH_WORD_SPLIT 2>/dev/null
set +o noclobber
tarcmd='tar'

dir=${LESSOPEN#\|}
dir=${dir%%lesspipe.sh*\%s}
dir=${dir%%/}
PATH=$PATH:$dir

cmd_exist () {
  command -v "$1" > /dev/null 2>&1 && return 0 || return 1
}
if [[ "$LESS_ADVANCED_PREPROCESSOR" = '' ]]; then
   NOL_A_P=_NO_L_A_P
fi

filecmd() {
  /nix/store/ja1iw47v9jkfgnj97l5cjivzn84160w2-file-5.41/bin/file -L -s "$@"
  /nix/store/ja1iw47v9jkfgnj97l5cjivzn84160w2-file-5.41/bin/file -L -s -i "$@" 2> /dev/null | sed -n 's/.*charset=/;/p' | tr a-z A-Z
}

TMPDIR=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}
sep=:                       # file name separator
altsep==                    # alternate separator character
if [[ -e "$1" && "$1" = *$sep* || "$1" = *$altsep ]]; then
  sep=$altsep
  xxx="${1%=}"
  set "$xxx"
fi
if cmd_exist mktemp; then
  tmpdir=$(mktemp -d "$TMPDIR/lesspipe.XXXXXXXXXX")

  nexttmp () {
    # nexttmp -d returns a directory
    mktemp "$1" "${tmpdir}/XXXXXXXX"
  }
else
  tmpdir="$TMPDIR"/lesspipe."$RANDOM"
  mkdir "$tmpdir"

  nexttmp () {
    new="$tmpdir/lesspipe.$RANDOM"
    [[ "$1" = -d ]] && mkdir "$new"
    echo "$new"
  }
fi
[[ -d "$tmpdir" ]] || exit 1
trap "rm -rf '$tmpdir'" 0
trap - PIPE

unset iconv
iconv() {
  if [[ -z "$iconv" ]]; then
    arg=$(printf "%s$(command iconv --help 2>/dev/null | \
      sed -n 's/.*\(--.*-subst=\)\(FORMATSTRING\).*/\1\\033[7m?\\033[m/p' | \
      tr \\n ' ')")
    if [[ -n "$arg" ]]; then
      iconv="command iconv -c $arg  -t //TRANSLIT"
    else
      iconv="command iconv -c"
    fi
  fi
  if $iconv "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    msg "append $sep to filename to view the $2 encoded data"
    $iconv "$@"
  fi
}

msg () {
  if [[ -n "$LESSQUIET" ]]; then
    return
  fi
  echo "==> $@"
}

filetype () {
  # wrapper for 'file' command
  typeset name
  name="$1"
  if [[ "$1" = - ]]; then
    name="$filen"
  fi
  if [[ ("$name" = *.br || "$name" = *.bro || "$name" = *.tbr) ]]; then
    # In current format, brotli can only be detected by extension
    echo " brotli compressed data"
    return
  fi
  if [[ "$1" = - ]]; then
    dd bs=40000 count=1 > "$tmpdir/file" 2>/dev/null
    set "$tmpdir/file" "$2"
  fi

  typeset return

  # file -b not supported by all versions of 'file'
  type="$(filecmd "$1" | cut -d : -f 2- )"
  if [[ "$type" = " empty" ]]; then
    # exit if file returns "empty" (e.g., with "less archive:nonexisting_file")
    exit 1
       # Open Office
  elif [[ "$type" = *OpenDocument\ Text* ]]; then
    return=" OpenDocument Text"
  elif [[ "$type" = *OpenDocument\ * || "$type" = *OpenOffice\.org\ 1\.x\ * ]]; then
      return=" OpenDocument"
       # Microsoft Office <  2007
  elif [[ "$type" = *Microsoft\ Office\ Document* && ("$name" = *.do[st]) ]] ||
       [[ "$type" = *Microsoft\ Office\ Word* ]]; then
       return=" Microsoft Word Document"
  elif [[ "$type" = *Microsoft\ Office\ Document* && ("$name" = *.pp[st]) ]] ||
       [[ "$type" = *Microsoft\ Office\ PowerPoint* ]]; then
       return=" Microsoft PowerPoint Document"
  elif [[ "$type" = *Microsoft\ Office\ Document* && ("$name" = *.xl[mst]) ]] || 
       [[ "$type" = *Microsoft\ Excel* ]]; then
       return=" Microsoft Excel Document"
  elif [[ "$type" = *Microsoft\ Office\ Document* ]]; then
       return=" Microsoft Office Document"
       # Microsoft Office >= 2007
  elif [[ ("$type" = *Zip\ archive* || "$type" =  Microsoft\ OOXML) && "$name" = *.do[ct][xm] ]] ||
       [[ "$type" = *Microsoft\ Word\ 2007* ]]; then
       return=" Microsoft Word 2007+"
  elif [[ ("$type" = *Zip\ archive* || "$type" =  Microsoft\ OOXML) && "$name" = *.pp[st][xm] ]] ||
       [[ "$type" = *Microsoft\ PowerPoint\ 2007* ]]; then
       return=" Microsoft PowerPoint 2007+"
  elif [[ ("$type" = *Zip\ archive* || "$type" =  Microsoft\ OOXML) && "$name" = *.xl[st][xmb] ]] ||
       [[ "$type" = *Microsoft\ Excel\ 2007* ]]; then
       return=" Microsoft Excel 2007+"
  elif [[ "$type" = *Zip\ archive* || "$type" =  Microsoft\ OOXML ]] ||
       [[ "$type" = *Microsoft\ *\ 2007* ]]; then
       return=" Microsoft Office 2007"
       # MP3
  elif [[ "$type" = *MPEG\ *layer\ 3\ audio* || "$type" = *MPEG\ *layer\ III* || "$type" = *mp3\ file* || "$type" = *MP3* ]]; then
    return="mp3"
       # Compressed Archives
  elif [[ "$type" != *lzip\ compressed* && ("$name" = *.lzma || "$name" = *.tlz) ]]; then
    return=" LZMA compressed data"
  elif [[ ("$type" = *Zip* || "$type" = *ZIP*) && ("$name" = *.jar || "$name" = *.xpi) ]]; then
    return=" Zip compressed Jar archive"
  elif [[ "$type" = *Hierarchical\ Data\ Format* && ("$name" = *.nc4) ]]; then
       return=" NetCDF Data Format data"
       # Sometimes a BSD makefile is identified as "troff or preprocessor input
       # text" probably due to its ".if" style directives.
  elif [[ "$type" = *roff\ *,* && ("$name" = */[Mm]akefile || "$name" = */[Mm]akefile.* || "$name" = */BSDmakefile || "$name" = *.mk) ]]; then
       return=" BSD makefile script,${type#*,}}"
       # Correct HTML Detection
  elif [[ ("$type" = *HTML* || "$type" = *ASCII*) && "$name" = *xml ]]; then
    return=" XML document text"
  elif [[ "$type" = *XML* && "$name" = *html ]]; then
    return=" HTML document text"
  fi

  if [[ -n "$return" ]]; then
    echo "$return"
    return
  elif [[ -n "$type" ]]; then
    echo "$type"
    return
  fi

  # file -b not supported by all versions of 'file'
  mime="$(file -i "$1" | cut -d : -f 2-)"
  if [[ "$mime" = \ text/* ]]; then
    return="text"
  elif [[ "$mime" = \ image/* ]]; then
    return="image"
  elif [[ "$mime" = \ audio/* ]]; then
    return="audio"
  elif [[ "$mime" = \ video/* ]]; then
    return="video"
  fi

  if [[ -n "$return" ]]; then
    echo "$return"
    return
  fi

  if [[ -n "$mime" ]]; then
    return="$mime"
  else
    return=""
  fi

  echo "$return"
}

show () {
  file1="${1%%$sep*}"
  rest1="${1#$file1}"
  while [[ "$rest1" = ::* ]]; do
    if [[ "$rest1" = "::" ]]; then
      break
    else
      rest1="${rest1#$sep$sep}"
      file1="${rest1%%$sep*}"
      rest1="${rest1#$file1}"
      file1="${1%$rest1}"
    fi
  done
  if [[ ! -e $file1  && "$file1" != '-' ]]; then
    return
  fi
  rest11="${rest1#$sep}"
  file2="${rest11%%$sep*}"
  rest2="${rest11#$file2}"
  while [[ "$rest2" = ::* ]]; do
    if [[ "$rest2" = "::" ]]; then
      break
    else
      rest2="${rest2#$sep$sep}"
      file2="${rest2%%$sep*}"
      rest2="${rest2#$file2}"
      file2="${rest11%$rest2}"
    fi
  done
  if [[ "$file2" != "" ]]; then
    in_file="-i$file2"
  fi
  rest2="${rest11#$file2}"
  rest11="$rest1"

  if cmd_exist html2text || cmd_exist elinks || cmd_exist links || cmd_exist lynx || cmd_exist w3m; then
    PARSEHTML=yes
  else
    PARSEHTML=no
  fi

  if [[ "$cmd" = "" ]]; then
    type=$(filetype "$file1") || exit 1
    if cmd_exist lsbom; then
      if [[ ! -f "$file1" ]]; then
        if [[ "$type" = *directory* ]]; then
      if [[ "$file1" = *.pkg ]]; then
        if [[ -f "$file1/Contents/Archive.bom" ]]; then
          type="bill of materials"
          file1="$file1/Contents/Archive.bom"
          msg "This is a Mac OS X archive directory, showing its contents (bom file)"
        fi
      fi
        fi
      fi
    fi
    get_cmd "$type" "$file1" "$rest1"
    if [[ "$cmd" != "" ]]; then
      show "-$rest1"
    else
      isfinal "$type" "$file1" "$rest11"
    fi
  elif [[ "$c1" = "" ]]; then
    c1=("${cmd[@]}")
    type=$("${c1[@]}" | filetype -) || exit 1
    get_cmd "$type" "$file1" "$rest1"
    if [[ "$cmd" != "" ]]; then
      show "-$rest1"
    else
      "${c1[@]}" | isfinal "$type" - "$rest11"
    fi
  elif [[ "$c2" = "" ]]; then
    c2=("${cmd[@]}")
    type=$("${c1[@]}" | "${c2[@]}" | filetype -) || exit 1
    get_cmd "$type" "$file1" "$rest1"
    if [[ "$cmd" != "" ]]; then
      show "-$rest1"
    else
      "${c1[@]}" | "${c2[@]}" | isfinal "$type" - "$rest11"
    fi
  elif [[ "$c3" = "" ]]; then
    c3=("${cmd[@]}")
    type=$("${c1[@]}" | "${c2[@]}" | "${c3[@]}" | filetype -) || exit 1
    get_cmd "$type" "$file1" "$rest1"
    if [[ "$cmd" != "" ]]; then
      show "-$rest1"
    else
      "${c1[@]}" | "${c2[@]}" | "${c3[@]}" | isfinal "$type" - "$rest11"
    fi
  elif [[ "$c4" = "" ]]; then
    c4=("${cmd[@]}")
    type=$("${c1[@]}" | "${c2[@]}" | "${c3[@]}" | "${c4[@]}" | filetype -) || exit 1
    get_cmd "$type" "$file1" "$rest1"
    if [[ "$cmd" != "" ]]; then
      show "-$rest1"
    else
      "${c1[@]}" | "${c2[@]}" | "${c3[@]}" | "${c4[@]}" | isfinal "$type" - "$rest11"
    fi
  elif [[ "$c5" = "" ]]; then
    c5=("${cmd[@]}")
    type=$("${c1[@]}" | "${c2[@]}" | "${c3[@]}" | "${c4[@]}" | "${c5[@]}" | filetype -) || exit 1
    get_cmd "$type" "$file1" "$rest1"
    if [[ "$cmd" != "" ]]; then
      echo "$0: Too many levels of encapsulation"
    else
      "${c1[@]}" | "${c2[@]}" | "${c3[@]}" | "${c4[@]}" | "${c5[@]}" | isfinal "$type" - "$rest11"
    fi
  fi
}

get_cmd () {
  cmd=
  typeset t
  if [[ "$1" = *[bg]zip*compress* || "$1" = *compress\'d\ * || "$1" = *packed\ data* || "$1" = *LZMA\ compressed* || "$1" = *lzip\ compressed* || "$1" = *[Xx][Zz]\ compressed* || "$1" = *Zstandard\ compressed* || "$1" = *[Bb]rotli\ compressed* || "$1" = *LZ4\ compressed* ]]; then ## added '#..then' to fix vim's syntax parsing
    if [[ "$3" = $sep$sep ]]; then
      return
    elif [[ "$1" = *bzip*compress* ]] && cmd_exist bzip2; then
      cmd=(bzip2 -cd "$2")
      if [[ "$2" != - ]]; then filen="$2"; fi
      case "$filen" in
        *.bz2) filen="${filen%.bz2}";;
        *.tbz) filen="${filen%.tbz}.tar";;
      esac
      return
    elif [[ "$1" = *lzip\ compressed* ]] && cmd_exist lzip; then
      cmd=(lzip -cd "$2")
      if [[ "$2" != - ]]; then filen="$2"; fi
      case "$filen" in
        *.lz) filen="${filen%.lz}";;
        *.tlz) filen="${filen%.tlz}.tar";;
      esac
    elif [[ "$1" = *LZMA\ compressed* ]] && cmd_exist lzma; then
      cmd=(lzma -cd "$2")
      if [[ "$2" != - ]]; then filen="$2"; fi
      case "$filen" in
        *.lzma) filen="${filen%.lzma}";;
        *.tlz) filen="${filen%.tlz}.tar";;
      esac
    elif [[ "$1" = *gzip\ compress* || "$1" =  *compress\'d\ * || "$1" = *packed\ data* ]]; then ## added '#..then' to fix vim's syntax parsing
      cmd=(gzip -cd "$2")
      if [[ "$2" != - ]]; then filen="$2"; fi
      case "$filen" in
        *.gz) filen="${filen%.gz}";;
        *.tgz) filen="${filen%.tgz}.tar";;
      esac
    elif [[ "$1" = *[Xx][Zz]\ compressed* ]] && cmd_exist xz; then
      cmd=(xz -cd "$2")
      if [[ "$2" != - ]]; then filen="$2"; fi
      case "$filen" in
       *.xz) filen="${filen%.xz}";;
       *.txz) filen="${filen%.txz}.tar";;
      esac
    elif [[ "$1" = *Zstandard\ compressed* ]] && cmd_exist zstd; then
      cmd=(zstd -cdqM1073741824 "$2")
      if [[ "$2" != - ]]; then filen="$2"; fi
      case "$filen" in
       *.zst) filen="${filen%.zst}";;
       *.tzst) filen="${filen%.tzst}.tar";;
      esac
    elif [[ "$1" = *[Bb]rotli\ compressed* ]] && cmd_exist brotli; then
      cmd=(brotli -cd -- "$2")
      if [[ "$2" != - ]]; then filen="$2"; fi
      case "$filen" in
       *.br|*.bro) filen="${filen%.*}";;
       *.tbr) filen="${filen%.*}.tar";;
      esac
    elif [[ "$1" = *LZ4\ compressed* ]] && cmd_exist lz4; then
      cmd=(lz4 -cdq "$2")
      if [[ "$2" != - ]]; then filen="$2"; fi
      case "$filen" in
       *.lz4) filen="${filen%.*}";;
       *.tl4|*.tz4|*.tlz4) filen="${filen%.*}.tar";;
      esac
    fi
    return
  fi

  rsave="$rest1"
  rest1="$rest2"
  if [[ "$file2" != "" ]]; then
    if [[ "$1" = *\ tar* || "$1" = *\   tar* ]]; then
      cmd=(istar "$2" "$file2")
    elif [[ "$1" = *Debian* ]]; then
      data="$(ar t "$2"|grep data.tar)"
      cmd2=("unpack_cmd" "$data")
      t=$(nexttmp)
      if [[ "$file2" = control/* ]]; then
        istemp "ar p" "$2" control.tar.gz | gzip -dc - > "$t"
        file2=".${file2:7}"
      else
        istemp "ar p" "$2" "$data" | $("${cmd2[@]}") > "$t"
      fi
      cmd=(istar "$t" "$file2")
    elif [[ "$1" = *RPM* ]] && cmd_exist cpio && ( cmd_exist rpm2cpio || cmd_exist rpmunpack ); then
      cmd=(isrpm "$2" "$file2")
    elif [[ "$1" = *Jar\ archive* || "$1" = *Java\ archive* ]] && cmd_exist fastjar; then
      cmd=(isjar "$2" "$file2")
    elif [[ "$1" = *Zip* || "$1" = *ZIP* || "$1" = *JAR* ]] && cmd_exist unzip; then
      cmd=(istemp "unzip -avp" "$2" "$file2")
    elif [[ "$1" = *RAR\ archive* ]]; then
      if cmd_exist unrar; then
        cmd=(istemp "unrar p -inul" "$2" "$file2")
      elif cmd_exist rar; then
        cmd=(istemp "rar p -inul" "$2" "$file2")
      elif cmd_exist bsdtar; then
        cmd=(istemp "bsdtar Oxf" "$2" "$file2")
      fi
    elif [[ "$1" = *7-zip\ archive* || "$1" = *7z\ archive* ]] && cmd_exist 7za; then
      cmd=(istemp "7za e -so" "$2" "$file2")
    elif [[ "$1" = *7-zip\ archive* || "$1" = *7z\ archive* ]] && cmd_exist 7zr; then
      cmd=(istemp "7zr e -so" "$2" "$file2")
    elif [[ "$1" = *[Cc]abinet* ]] && cmd_exist cabextract; then
      cmd=(iscab "$2" "$file2")
    elif [[ "$1" = *\ ar\ archive* ]]; then
      cmd=(istemp "ar p" "$2" "$file2")
    elif [[ "$1" = *ISO\ 9660* ]] && cmd_exist isoinfo; then
      cmd=(isoinfo "-i$2" "-x$file2")
    fi
    if [[ "$cmd" != "" ]]; then
      filen="$file2"
    fi
  fi
}

iscab () {
  typeset t
  if [[ "$1" = - ]]; then
    t=$(nexttmp)
    cat > "$t"
    set "$t" "$2"
  fi
  cabextract -pF "$2" "$1"
}

istar () {
  $tarcmd Oxf "$1" "$2" 2>/dev/null
}
 ...

 isrpm () {
  if cmd_exist rpm2cpio && cmd_exist cpio; then
    typeset t
    if [[ "$1" = - ]]; then
      t=$(nexttmp)
      cat > "$t"
      set "$t" "$2"
    fi
    # setup $b as a batch file containing "$b.out"
    typeset b
    b="$(nexttmp -d)"
    rpm2cpio "$1" 2>/dev/null|(cd "$b" || return; pax -r "$2" 2>/dev/null)
    cat "$b/$2"
  elif cmd_exist rpmunpack && cmd_exist cpio; then
    b=$(nexttmp -d)
    cat "$1" | rpmunpack | gzip -cd |(cd "$b" || return; pax -r "$2" 2>/dev/null)
    cat "$b/$2"
  fi
}

isjar () {
  case "$2" in
    /*) echo "lesspipe can't unjar files with absolute paths" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    ../*) echo "lesspipe can't unjar files with ../ paths" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
  typeset d
  d=$(nexttmp -d)
  [[ -d "$d" ]] || exit 1
  cat "$1" | (
    cd "$d" || return
    fastjar -x "$2"
    if [[ -f "$2" ]]; then
      cat "$2"
    fi
  )
}

#parsexml () { nodash "elinks -dump -default-mime-type text/xml" "$1"; }
parsehtml () {
  if [[ "$PARSEHTML" = no ]]; then
    msg "No suitable tool for HTML parsing found, install one of html2text, elinks, links, lynx or w3m"
    return
  elif cmd_exist html2text; then
    if [[ "$1" = - ]]; then html2text; else html2text "$1"; fi
  elif cmd_exist lynx; then
    if [[ "$1" = - ]]; then set - -stdin; fi
    lynx -dump -force_html "$1" && return
  elif cmd_exist w3m; then
    nodash "w3m -dump -T text/html" "$1"
  elif cmd_exist elinks; then
    nodash "elinks -dump -force-html" "$1"
  elif cmd_exist links; then
    if [[ "$1" = - ]]; then set - -stdin; fi
    links -dump -force_html "$1"
  fi
}

unpack_cmd() {
    cmd_string="cat"
    if [[ "$1" == *xz ]]; then
      cmd_string="xz -dc -"
    elif [[ "$1" == *gz ]]; then
      cmd_string="gzip -dc -"
    elif [[ "$1" == *bz2 ]]; then
      cmd_string="bzip2 -dc -"
    elif [[ "$1" == *lzma ]]; then
      cmd_string="lzma -dc -"
    elif [[ "$1" == *zst ]]; then
      cmd_string="zstd -dcqM1073741824 -"
    elif [[ ("$1" == *br || "$1" == *bro) ]]; then
      cmd_string="brotli -dc -"
    elif [[ "$1" == *lz4 ]]; then
      cmd_string="lz4 -dcq -"
    fi
    echo "$cmd_string"
}

isfinal() {
  typeset t
  if [[ $3 = $sep$sep ]]; then
    cat "$2"
    return
  elif [[ $3 = $sep* ]]; then
    if [[ $3 = "$sep" ]]; then
      msg "append :. or :<filetype> to activate syntax highlighting"
    else
      lang=${3#$sep}
      lang="-l${lang#.}"
      lang=${lang%%-l }
      if cmd_exist code2color; then
        code2color $PPID ${in_file:+"$in_file"} "$lang" "$2"
        if [[ $? = 0 ]]; then
          return
        fi
      fi
    fi
    cat "$2"
    return
  fi

  lang="$(echo $LANG | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"
  # color requires -r or -R when calling less
  typeset COLOR
  if [[ $(/nix/store/8636r3d8rsk7c3l5xcgb1mn37pkfc84k-ncurses-6.3-p20220507/bin/tput colors) -ge 8 && ("$LESS" = *-*r* || "$LESS" = *-*R*) ]]; then
    COLOR="--color=always"
  fi

  if [[ "$1" = *No\ such* ]]; then
    exit 1
  elif [[ "$1" = *directory* ]]; then
    cmd=(ls -lA $COLOR "$2")
    if ! ls $COLOR > /dev/null 2>&1; then
      cmd=(ls -lA -G "$2")
      if ! ls -lA -G > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        cmd=(ls -lA "$2")
      fi
    fi
    msg "This is a directory, showing the output of ${cmd[@]}"
    if [[ ${cmd[2]} = '-G' ]]; then
      CLICOLOR_FORCE=1 "${cmd[@]}"
    else
      "${cmd[@]}"
    fi
  elif [[ "$1" = *\ tar* || "$1" = *\   tar* ]]; then
    msg "use tar_file${sep}contained_file to view a file in the archive"
    if [[ -n $COLOR ]] && cmd_exist tarcolor; then
      $tarcmd tvf "$2" | tarcolor
    else
      $tarcmd tvf "$2"
    fi
  elif [[ "$1" = *RPM* ]]; then
    header="use RPM_file${sep}contained_file to view a file in the RPM"
    if cmd_exist rpm; then
      echo "$header"
      istemp "rpm -qivp" "$2"
      header="";
    fi
    if cmd_exist cpio && cmd_exist rpm2cpio; then
      echo $header
      echo "================================= Content ======================================"
      istemp rpm2cpio "$2" 2>/dev/null|cpio -i -tv 2>/dev/null
    elif cmd_exist cpio && cmd_exist rpmunpack; then
      echo $header
      echo "================================= Content ======================================"
      cat "$2" | rpmunpack | gzip -cd | cpio -i -tv 2>/dev/null
    else
      msg "please install rpm2cpio or rpmunpack to see the contents of RPM files"
    fi
  elif [[ "$1" = *roff* ]] && cmd_exist groff; then
    DEV=utf8
    if [[ $lang != *utf*8* ]]; then
      if [[ "$lang" = ja* ]]; then
        DEV=nippon
      else
        DEV=latin1
      fi
    fi
    MACRO=andoc
    if [[ "$2" = *.me ]]; then
      MACRO=e
    elif [[ "$2" = *.ms ]]; then
      MACRO=s
    fi
    msg "append $sep to filename to view the nroff source"
    groff -s -p -t -e -T$DEV -m$MACRO "$2"
  elif [[ "$1" = *Debian* ]]; then
    msg "use Deb_file${sep}contained_file to view a file in the Deb"
    if cmd_exist dpkg; then
      nodash "dpkg -I" "$2"
    else
      echo
      istemp "ar p" "$2" control.tar.gz | gzip -dc - | $tarcmd tvf - | sed -r 's/(.{48})\./\1control/'
    fi
    data=$(ar t "$2"|grep data.tar)
    cmd2=("unpack_cmd" "$data")
    echo
    istemp "ar p" "$2" "$data" | $("${cmd2[@]}") | $tarcmd tvf -
  # do not display all perl text containing pod using perldoc
  #elif [[ "$1" = *Perl\ POD\ document\ text* || "$1" = *Perl5\ module\ source\ text* ]]; then
  elif [[ "$1" = *Perl\ POD\ document\ text$NOL_A_P* ]] && cmd_exist perldoc; then
    msg "append $sep to filename to view the perl source"
    istemp perldoc "$2"
  elif [[ "$1" = *\ script* ]]; then
    set "plain text" "$2"
  elif [[ "$1" = *text\ executable* ]]; then
    set "plain text" "$2"
  elif [[ "$1" = *PostScript$NOL_A_P* ]]; then
    if cmd_exist pstotext; then
      msg "append $sep to filename to view the postscript file"
      nodash pstotext "$2"
    elif cmd_exist ps2ascii; then
      msg "append $sep to filename to view the postscript file"
      istemp ps2ascii "$2"
    else
      msg "install pstotext or ps2ascii to view a textual representation of the file contents"
    fi
  elif [[ "$1" = *executable* ]]; then
    msg "append $sep to filename to view the raw file"
    nodash strings "$2"
  elif [[ "$1" = *\ ar\ archive* ]]; then
    msg "use library${sep}contained_file to view a file in the archive"
    istemp "ar vt" "$2"
  elif [[ "$1" = *shared* ]] && cmd_exist nm; then
    msg "This is a dynamic library, showing the output of nm"
    istemp nm "$2"
  elif [[ "$1" = *Jar\ archive* ]] && cmd_exist fastjar; then
    msg "use jar_file${sep}contained_file to view a file in the archive"
    nodash "fastjar -tf" "$2"
  elif [[ "$1" = *Zip* || "$1" = *ZIP* || "$1" = *JAR* ]] && cmd_exist unzip; then
    msg "use zip_file${sep}contained_file to view a file in the archive"
    istemp "unzip -lv" "$2"
  elif [[ "$1" = *RAR\ archive* ]]; then
    if cmd_exist unrar; then
      msg "use rar_file${sep}contained_file to view a file in the archive"
      istemp "unrar v" "$2"
    elif cmd_exist rar; then
      msg "use rar_file${sep}contained_file to view a file in the archive"
      istemp "rar v" "$2"
    elif cmd_exist bsdtar; then
      msg "use rar_file${sep}contained_file to view a file in the archive"
      istemp "bsdtar tvf" "$2"
    fi 
  elif [[ "$1" = *7-zip\ archive* || "$1" = *7z\ archive* ]] && cmd_exist 7za; then
    typeset res
    res=$(istemp "7za l" "$2")
    if [[ "$res" = *\ 1\ file* ]]; then
      msg "a 7za archive containing one file was silently unpacked"
      if [[ "$2" != - ]]; then
        7za e -so "$2" 2>/dev/null
      else
        # extract name of temporary file containing the 7za archive
        t=${res#*Listing\ archive:\ }
        t2="
"
        t=${t%%$t2*}
        7za e -so "$t" 2>/dev/null
      fi
    else
      msg "use 7za_file${sep}contained_file to view a file in the archive"
      echo "$res"
    fi
  elif [[ "$1" = *7-zip\ archive* || "$1" = *7z\ archive* ]] && cmd_exist 7zr; then
    typeset res
    res=$(istemp "7zr l" "$2")
    if [[ "$res" = *\ 1\ file* ]]; then
      msg "a 7za archive containing one file was silently unpacked"
      if [[ "$2" != - ]]; then
        7zr e -so "$2" 2>/dev/null
      else
        # extract name of temporary file containing the 7za archive
        t=${res#*Listing\ archive:\ }
        t2="
"
        t=${t%%$t2*}
        7zr e -so "$t" 2>/dev/null
      fi
    else
      msg "use 7za_file${sep}contained_file to view a file in the archive"
      echo "$res"
    fi
  elif [[ "$1" = *[Cc]abinet* ]] && cmd_exist cabextract; then
    msg "use cab_file${sep}contained_file to view a file in the cabinet"
    istemp "cabextract -l" "$2"
  elif [[ "$1" = *\ DVI* ]] && cmd_exist dvi2tty; then
    msg "append $sep to filename to view the raw DVI file"
    isdvi "$2"
  elif [[ "$PARSEHTML" = yes && "$1" = *HTML$NOL_A_P* ]]; then
    msg "append $sep to filename to view the HTML source"
    parsehtml "$2"
  elif [[ "$1" = *PDF* ]] && cmd_exist pdftotext; then
    if [[ "$PARSEHTML" = yes ]]; then
      msg "append $sep to filename to view the PDF source"
      istemp "pdftotext -htmlmeta" "$2" - | parsehtml -
    else
      msg "append $sep to filename to view the PDF source"
      istemp pdftotext "$2" -
    fi
  elif [[ "$PARSEHTML" = yes && "$1" = *PDF* ]] && cmd_exist pdftohtml; then
    msg "append $sep to filename to view the PDF source"
    t=$(nexttmp)
    cat "$2" > "$t"; pdftohtml -stdout "$t" | parsehtml -
  elif [[ "$1" = *PDF* ]] && cmd_exist pdfinfo; then
      msg "append $sep to filename to view the PDF source"
      istemp pdfinfo "$2"
  ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you try `strings file.pdf|less` (to filter only text)?

Comment: It might help to add the version off `less` you're using (eg `less --version`, any environment settings (eg `env | grep LESS`).  On my system I have `LESSOPEN` which points to a script that does different things based on file extension; eg for `.jpg` files it will try to run `identify` instead of showing the file contents.

Answer (score 3):

1. *Why is there "==> append : to filename to view the PDF source" ?*

   Because there is this code in your `lesspipe.sh` file, displaying a help message meant to help you use it:

   ```bash
   elif [[ "$1" = *PDF* ]] && cmd_exist pdftotext; then
     if [[ "$PARSEHTML" = yes ]]; then
       msg "append $sep to filename to view the PDF source"
       istemp "pdftotext -htmlmeta" "$2" - | parsehtml -
     else
       msg "append $sep to filename to view the PDF source"
       istemp pdftotext "$2" -
     fi
   ```
2. *How can I suppress it?*

   Modify this part of your `lesspipe`.

Comment: @tim, With respect to the original question: it will help to have the broader picture, know  what you want to do, and why.

Answer (score 1):

So you have `LESSOPEN` to point to a script which is what is doing this work.

You have some possible options:

1. `unset LESSOPEN` so now none of this magic will happen and you'll always get the raw file
2. modify the script to remove the warning
3. `cat filename.pdf | less`.  Normally this will bypass `LESSOPEN`